# Is it possible to conditionally enable an attribute like `derive`?

Tags: rust

I have added a feature in my crate which adds `serde` support. However, I don't quite understand how to use it properly:

```
// #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)] // goes to:

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
#[cfg(feature = "serde_support")]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct;
```

This code treats everything below `cfg(feature)` as conditionally compiled, so without my `serde_support` feature my crate does not have `MyStruct` also.

I have tried to wrap it with braces but it gives another error:

Code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
#[cfg(feature = "serde_support")] {
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
}
pub struct MyStruct;
```

Error:

```
error: expected item after attributes
  --> mycrate/src/lib.rs:65:33
   |
65 | #[cfg(feature = "serde_support")] {
   |                                 ^
```

So how to do this?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can use the `cfg_attr(a, b)` attribute:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "serde_support", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub struct MyStruct;
```

It's described in the [Rust reference about "conditional compilation"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#conditional-compilation):

> ```
> #[cfg_attr(a, b)]
> item
> ```
>
> Will be the same as `#[b] item` if `a` is set by `cfg`, and `item` otherwise.

Comment: But how do you get the docs to say that `MyStruct` only implements `Serialize` and `Deserialize` if the `serde_support` feature is enabled?

Comment: @RBF06 I'm guessing by now you probably already got a way to do this. If not might be better as a separate question.