# How to make the #![no_main] attribute conditional?

Tags: rust

I'm using `#![no_main]` so I can use SDL2main on Windows and Android but I would like to have it conditionally used so I can run Rust's built-in test harness on Linux.

I've tried:

```
#[cfg(not(test))]
#![no_main]
```

and

```
include!(concat!("cfg_test_", cfg!(test), ".rs"));
```

where `cfg_test_false.rs` contains `#![no_main]` and `cfg_test_true.rs` doesn't.

Neither of them work.

I know I can fall back to generating `main.rs` using `build.rs` but I'm hoping there is a better way, as from what I know, it will have to generate the `main.rs` in the `src` directory instead of `${OUT_DIR}`.

Comment: does `#![cfg_attr(not(test), no_main)]` work?
For using android you need a cdylib, not a binary.

Comment: Hi! I think your question is answered by [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551113/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-derive-with-features/42551386). tl;dr: `#[cfg_attr(not(test), no_main)]`. But I'm not sure if I would actually close this question as a dupe since the question I linked asks about *deriving* and only happens to have an answer that fits here, too. Maybe someone else has an opinion about this.

Comment: This should be more prominent in rust-lang's docs as I couldn't find that info after an hour of googling

Comment: @Tim I hadn't actually gotten around to building on android yet, i just know that sdl is a pain to use on android because you can't even use something like `WinMain`. I think Windows Mobile and iOS are equally painful, but don't remember for sure