# How do I use cfg to set different attributes on different target architectures?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I have a struct which must be 16-byte aligned when targeting `wasm`.

How can I do this?

So for instance, I want to have this struct on `wasm`:

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")] <- not sure about this
#[repr(c, align(16))]
struct Foo {...}
```

And this on all other architectures:

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")] <- not sure about this
#[repr(c)]
struct Foo {...}
```

Is this possible to achieve with cfg?  If so how?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551113/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-enable-an-attribute-like-derive

Comment: More like this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html

Comment: Also nit: `repr(c)` does not exist, it's `repr(C)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like its possible with [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute):

```rs
#[cfg_attr(not(target_arch = "wasm32"), repr(C))]
#[cfg_attr(target_arch = "wasm32", repr(C, align(16)))]
struct Foo { ... }
```

Comment: I yield my answer in favour of yours.